# Netbeans + jquery = error

Tags: jquery, netbeans

I'm working in a php project and Netbeans insists on marking lines like

```
        $.get("/adminc/utilsAjax.php", { function: "orderIsOpenOrClosed", orderID: orderID, rand: randn }, function(data)
```

and the closings

```
        });
```

As errors

I tried using the non minifierd version of jquery and no change.
It's like Netbeans ignores the jquery syntax.
Any ideas?

Comment: what about if you quote the hash keys like `function`,`orderId` etc.?

Comment: Strange, I am currently using netbeans with jquery, so i doubt thats the issue. Are you sure the syntax is correct? You have the word function and then the function as a string name. Is that correct? Netbeans may be expecting () after the function keyword.

Comment: Yeah like @prodigitalson says, the function is a reserved word, and in object notation may require quotes

Comment: wow, how lame of me! Please, make it an answer so I can accept it. Thanks

Comment: Looking at the syntax highlighting always helps ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bodman Said, `function` is a reserved word so you need to quote that. But you may also need to quote all the hash keys for netbeans to interpret them correctly for example:

```
    $.get("/adminc/utilsAjax.php", {
        "function": "orderIsOpenOrClosed", 
        "orderID": orderID, 
        "rand": randn 
      }, 
      function(data){
        // fun body
    });
```

Answer (score 4):

The "function" is a reserved word, and in object notation may require quotes, Netbeans is expecting () after the Function key word.

Answer (score 0):

You have missed a `{` after `function(data)`